# Having Trouble Passing Information Between Swift Files

Tags: swift, delegates

I am trying to pass information from one swift file to another view controller by using delegate protocol and another init class file. My issue arrises when I call the variable that I want transferred, and it shows up as a nil. I want to be able to pass the ageDescription from the one swift file to another when saveButton is tapped. I was wondering what I can change so that the variable can be called upon.

First View Controller

```
@IBAction func ageChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch age.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        print("Under 18")
        var ageDescription = "under 18"
        let data = Data(ageData: ageDescription)

    case 1:
        print("Over 18")
        var ageDescription = "over 18"
       let data = Data(ageData: ageDescription)
    case 2:
        print("Strictly over 21")
        var ageDescription = "strictly over 21"
   let data = Data(ageData: ageDescription)
    default:
        print("IDK")
    }

}
```

Other View Controller

```
@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    func getData(data: Data) {
        print(data.ageData)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a protocol in the class in which you will get the data above viewcontroller like this

```
protocol ageDescriptionDelegte {

    func sendageDescriptiongetData(data: Data)
} 
class ViewController: UIViewController {
weak var delegate: PassDateDelegte?
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
   self.delegate?.sendageDescriptiongetData(ageDescription)//pass your age description

    }
}
```

In your view controller where you want to access the data conform to the protocol

```
extension ViewController2: ageDescriptionDelegte {

func sendageDescriptiongetData(data: Data) {
print(data)// this will give you the age description 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prepareForSegue override.

Just create a variable in the other VC you're segueing to and assign it in the override.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // store the instance of Other view controller 
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as OtherVCclassName
    destinationVC.variableInNewVC = self.ageDescription
}
```

You'll also need to declare the ageDescription variable outside of a method as a global.

Comment: I've inputted the prepareForSegue override into my OtherVC but it doesn't recognize self.ageDescription. Perhaps I haven't set up the global variable correctly? I initialized [var ageDescription : String = String()] in the first VC. Thanks for your patience as I am new to Swift.

Comment: You want to override the segue method on the view controller with the button that is performing that segue, the one you are coming from, not going to.  And just make sure that variable declaration inside the class but not inside any method.

Comment: If you can't figure that out, post your class names and I'll edit my answer with the exact way you need to do it.